# Cross-validation for parameter tuning in data mining process (KDD)

Tags: classification, cross-validation, data-mining, neural-networks, knowledge-discovery

In my project I want to compare different classification algorithms to solve a specific problem with a specific dataset. To do this, I divided the dataset in 2 parts.

1. With the first (bigger) part I am doing cross validation. In this step I try to find out the best parameters for each algorithm (for example the number of neurons in the hidden layer of a neural network), as well as search for the best threshold for the classification.
2. I use the second part of the dataset to evaluate and compare the algorithms, using the parameters found on the previously step.

My question: **How these two steps (parameter tunning and generalization test) can be mapped in a data mining process (KDD, SEMMA or CRISP-DM)?**

Should the two steps be two different iteration of the process or perhaps each step should be a different project/process (with the initial stages in common)?

Comment: Can you explain how you think KDD or SEMMA or CRISP-DM is related to the very general procedure of train-test-validate splits?

Comment: @Sycorax At that time I was starting an academic project and I was wondering if I would need to use and describe the data mining process used. Precisely I would like to understand the relationship between KDD and what I was doing (your question). At the end, I did not use any of them directly. My master dissertation is in portuguese but if you want you can check my paper you can access: [http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1516-31802017000300234&lng=en&nrm=iso&tlng=en]

Comment: It sounds like you know the answer to your question; it's perfectly acceptable to write an answer to  your own question